Hibernate query with IN operator, how to keep parameters order for the results?
I am trying to keep the order results of a query with the IN operatore the same as the input parameters.
I have a query like this
List<String> students = Arrays.asList("Leo", "Tom", "Meg", "Barbara");
Query q = session.createQuery("from Students where name in :names");
q.setParameterList("names", students);

When I run the query the results are ordered by the id of the students (or whatever the primary key is), but I would like to keep the order of the parameter (so "Leo", "Tom, "Meg" and "Barbara" last), is there a way do to this?
I am using Hibernate 5.6.15

That's not how this works, i.e. you're basically providing a set of values to filter on. You could fiddle with the query and provide an additional value to sort by but that may be way too complex and fragile. Instead, why not order the results when you got them? Just assign a list index to each element based on it's name's position in the input list. - However, what exactly are you trying to achieve here? Why would Leo be sorted before Tom and Meg?

I get this data from an internal search engine.once I got it I query the db to retrieve additional data not present in the search engine dataset and show it to the user but I want to keep the search engine result order because I have the more relevant results on top

The suggestion still stands. If the query basically adds details to search results then try to add the query results (details) to the search engine results by mapping them via a suitable key (name might be it in your case but what if there are multiple Leos or Megs?).

It would be better to follow Thomas suggestion.
Anyway in Postgresql:
 select * from student where name IN ('Pekka', 'Beta', 'Gama','Alpha') 
  order by position(name::text in 'Pekka,Beta,Gama,Alpha');

Nevertheless, i am not sure how to achieve the same via hibernate. Let's try.


You can sort one list based on another. May be this is what you are trying to achieve?
        List<String> students = Arrays.asList("Pekka", "Beta", "Gama","Alpha","j");
        Query q = session.createQuery("from Student where name in :names");
        q.setParameter("names", students);
        List<Student> listToSort = q.getResultList();
        Collections.sort(listToSort, Comparator.comparing(item ->
                students.indexOf(item.getName())));
        System.out.println(listToSort);



Without lambda expression
            Comparator<Student> compare = new Comparator<Student>() {
            public int compare(Student v1, Student v2) {
                return students.indexOf(v1.getName()) - students.indexOf(v2.getName());
            }
        };
            Collections.sort(listToSort,compare);

